# Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property when referencing models to eachother

Tags: database, entity-framework-core, relational-database, blazor

I have two models that I am trying to connect in my DB

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Message> Messages { get; set;  }

}
```

and

```
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MessageContent { get; set; }  
    public User Sender { get; set; }
    public User Receiver { get; set;  }

}
```

when i try to add migration im getting the error:

```
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Message.Sender' of type 'User'.
```

The idea is that a user has a list of messages that they have sent, and every message has a record of a user who sent the message, and another id of a user who received the message.

what am i missing here?

Edit: this is a blazor web assembly app using EFCORE

Answer (score 1):

Problem you are having is, `Message` entity has two relationships (foreign keys) to the `User` entity. And there is only one navigational property in `User`. EF does not know which relationship you are referring to. When there is only one relationship this will work. But when you have multiple relationships you have to explicitly specify to which each navigational property maps.

try doing this,

```
[InverseProperty("Sender")] 
public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; } //virtual key word not required
```

In your case since `User` has two kinds of relationships with `Message`, I would have two navigation properties like this,

```
[InverseProperty("Sender")] 
public ICollection<Message> MessagesSent { get; set; }

[InverseProperty("Reciever")] 
public ICollection<Message> MessagesRecieved { get; set; }
```

Refer this article for more info: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx